# Sending large number notifications generates excess memory error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have stored tokens of my app users in a node name "tokens".

In firebase functions I am creating a function that reads all the tokens, which are 5000+, and sends notification to each token.

ie:

```
return  admin.database().ref('root/tokens/').once('value')
                    .then(function(dataSnapshot){

                            dataSnapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {

                                var token = snapshot.val(); 
                                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options );

                            }
```

But I am getting error in Firebase functions log saying:

[image]

What do I need to resolve this error? Do I need to change my code?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that your Cloud Function ran out of memory. So you will either need to increase the memory that the function can use, or decrease the memory that it requires.

To change the available memory, have a look at the documentation on [setting timeout and memory allocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation).

---

Unrelated: consider using the new [`sendAll` method of the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_a_batch_of_messages) to reduce the number of API calls you need to make. It will speed up the execution of your code, and may reduce memory usage a bit.

Comment: sendAll function also has limit of only 100 messages at a time. Anyhow, I have dropped this option altogether.